# Designing Java application for multiple memory intensive requests

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

What is the best way to design an application to perform huge in-memory operations without running out of heap space in java?. There will be multiple requests from the users to perform this operation and it might quickly run out of heap space. Some of the ways I can think of are:

- Invoking child processes to perform the task for each request.
- Creating a a thread pool with fixed threads to process the request, but if it is memory intensive task, there would be a risk of running out of heap space.
- Introducing JMS

Comment: What kind of data structure are you handling in the space-consuming operations?

Comment: the task is to generate a huge pdf with lot of data and I have not yet decided on the data structure.